# ¿Cómo crear subcarpetas dentro de carpetas con cmd?

Tags: windows, bucle-for, cmd

Se desea crear subcarpetas con las fechas dentro de varias carpetas con el código FOR /d en cmd hasta el momento solo ejecute este código

```
FOR /D /r %f in ("*") DO (mkdir "15-03-2021" "16-03-2021" "17-03-2021" "18-03-2021" "19-03-2021")
```

Solo crea las carpetas 15-03-2021 .. 19-03-2021 dentro de la carpeta principal, pero se desea crear como se muestra en la imagen.
Lo ideal es que se pueda realizar como la segunda imagen, pero teniendo en cuenta que son más subcarpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuál es el criterio para las carpetas más externas? Las que tienen nombre 01xxx, 02xxx, hay una lista de nombres predefinida? Misma pregunta para `Aprendo en casa`

Comment: yo tengo una carpeta el la cual tengo sub carpetas con nombres de una lista de colegio, lo que deseo realizar es crear carpetas con fecha dentro de cada carpeta de cada alumno, por lo que quise usar el for pero no me funciona :(

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ver con esto:

```
mkdir carpeta1/carpeta2/carpeta3/carpeta4
```

De esta forma, carpeta4 está dentro de 3, 3 de 2 y 2 de 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yo de esta forma, por pasos:

Te diriges hacia el directorio donde quieres crear la carpeta o carpeptas

Ejemplo:

```
cd Documentos
documentos> mkdir Carpeta1
cd carpeta1 
documentos/carpeta1> mkdir subcarpeta1
```

De esta forma puedes crear subcarpetas dentro de carpetas principales.

Espero te sirva, saludos